# Set up VPN programmatically on Android

Tags: android, vpn, ipsec

I need to implement VPN IPsec on android programmatically i.e. connecting, disconnecting on the click of button inside my own app, without asking user explicitly. 
Came across VpnService(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) and its implementation i.e. toyvpn (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/)

Some of the threads already discussing the same:

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8915
- [How to configure VPN programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444757/how-to-configure-vpn-programatically)
- [programmatically setting up a vpn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418353/programmatically-setting-up-a-vpn)
- [How to programmatically create a new VPN interface with Android 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921457/how-to-programmatically-create-a-new-vpn-interface-with-android-4-0)
- [Android: Sample Code to use own VPN connection in Android 4.0 using VPNService API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177522/android-sample-code-to-use-own-vpn-connection-in-android-4-0-using-vpnservice-a)

But didn't find any satisfactory answer. What I inferred is, either I have to write whole implementation by myself. Or something about hidden API in Android.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm facing a similar scenario and wanted to know what you finally did. 
Thanks! :D

Comment: Nope! My requirement changed. So i used openvpn: https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn

Comment: @robertohuertasm did you find a solution for this? I am looking to open a L2TP connection programmatically

Comment: @JadChahine sorry, I can't help. Same as the original author, the requirement finally changed.