# How connect VPN Network programmatically in android?

Tags: android, api, vpn

API-14 Available to implement vpn service for android. How to implement it?

Comment: Please do your homework before you ask any questions and SO is not the right place to ask for SOURCE CODE. People here are trying to help you and we can't do it without your efforts.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer open source project openvpn for reference about how to implement VPN services in android.you may also like to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921457/how-to-programmatically-create-a-new-vpn-interface-with-android-4-0)

http://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For that first you need to decalre VPN service in you code like as follows

```
 <service android:name=".ExampleVpnService"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.net.VpnService"/>
     </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

[And you can also check this link for more details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html)