# Create VPN on Android programmatically

Tags: android, vpn, pptp

I know this has been asked before, but most of them are 3 to 4 years ago with no definite answers. I would like to know if this is already possible as of 2015.

Comment: The last commit was 6 days ago
https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn

Answer (score 15):

Also there seems to API working for that in Android 22.
VpnService and VpnService.Builder.
Also you should check out this sample https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/

Update:
github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn seems much better option when using openVPN profiles

Comment: i have gone their but it seems like its not making vpn instead vpn interface.i dont know if my idea of vpn CRUD is really posible or i just need to code it on my own vpn profile and vpn protocol.

Comment: I found your answer accidentally, but this link is so useful for me. thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is an API for an android VpnService (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) which was added in API 14.

In addition, some CyanogenMod ROMs have an openvpn binary preinstalled.

Answer (score 4):

API is one for OpenVPN:

http://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/

This provides one potential VPN solution that you are fully in control of (the server is open-source also), but it is not PPTP or IPSec. If you understand the PPTP protocol, it should be possible to use this as a model to implement such a VPN client.

I think u find more information here:

[How to programmatically create a new VPN interface with Android 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921457/how-to-programmatically-create-a-new-vpn-interface-with-android-4-0)