# PPTP Android VPN Client Application without ROOT Access

Tags: android, pptp

> i want to create a PPTP Android Client to just Create an intent to send data automatically in setting of Default VPN and create a profile with sended username password and hostname through PPTP and just connect

[I Read this Link to create interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921457/how-to-programmatically-create-a-new-vpn-interface-with-android-4-0?answertab=active#tab-top)

> But Not know how to completely do it without rooted phone 
>   Thanks :)